# Catching characters that do not pass regex validation

Tags: python, regex, django

In a Django website of mine, I allow usernames that are alphanumeric, and/or contain `@` `_` `.` `+` `-`. Moreover, whitespaces are allowed too. I've written a simple regex to ensure this: `'^[\w\s.@+-]+$'`.

It might be an obvious question, but how do I capture characters that **do not** pass regex validation? I want to display such characters in a tool tip to my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `'[^...]'` notation in order to negate the character set `'...'`. The following will give you a set of all the unwanted characters:

```
> name = 'abc%&/()45 -:'
> set(re.findall(r'[^\w\s.@+-]', name))
set(['%', '&', ')', '(', '/', ':'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the carat inside of square brackets (e.g. `[^...]`) makes it an inverse. So, for example, `[A-Za-z0-9_]` would match alpha numerics and underscores, whereas `[^A-Za-z0-9_]` would match anything that is *not* alpha numerics or underscores. In your case, the regex you seem to want is `r'^[^\w\s\.\@\+\-]+$'`.